# Why can't i find git password in osxkeychain?

Tags: git, macos

I set `git config --local credential.helper osxkeychain`  which works fine.
I tried pull and git don't ask my name and password as i expect.

But when i check my osxkeychain, search git or github or gitlab etc. Nothing i can found, this is weried, shouldn't the password suppose to be stored here?

Hope someone can answer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there. Look under "login" keychain, category "Passwords". It shows up as an internet password (blue-background @ symbol), name shows the hostname, e.g. "github.com". The application that manages the passwords is "git-credential-osxkeychain".

Comment: Great Answer!Thank u very much! It can't be found through search git or something because the name is my gitlab website instead of XXX.gitxxx.